Guidelines for finding a preconditioner for a matrix that is "near" singular
Given a large non-symmetric non-sparse matrix $A=(a_{m,n})$ with the property that the columns of $A$ are "close", making the matrix very ill-conditioned and near singular. Edit: {Suppose, in addition, that you have a compact form for the $a_{m,n}$.} For example, consider $A$ with $a_{m,n}= \log(m) \cos(\log(n))$ (maybe this isn't an ideal example, but the idea is that $a_{m,n}$ and $a_{m,n+1}$ are close). Suppose we're interested in finding a preconditioner for $A$, what are some "things to try" that would give an idea of what a good preconditioner might be if the well-known preconditioners (e.g. Jacobi, etc...) didn't help?

All good preconditioners make use of the fact that we know underlying properties of the matrix, such as where it comes from. You cannot find good preconditioners for matrices you know nothing about, other than that it is poorly conditioned.
